# I can't find a pattern in the examples

Tags: console-application

I am working on a task for a company intern position but I am having some problems with understanding part of the condition itself. This question is focused more on problem solving manner, than writing code. The code is not an issue.

The important part of the condition:

The builders must cover a rectangular area of size ​M×N (​M and ​N are even numbers) with two layers of bricks that are rectangles of size 1×2. The first layer of the bricks has already been completed. The second layer ( in an effort to make the brickwork really strong) must be created in away that no brick in it lies exactly on a brick from the first layer. However, it is allowed half of the same brick to lie on the same brick on the second layer. Create a console app that accepts input parameters for the given layout of the bricks for the first layer, determine the possible layout of the​ second one, or prove that it is impossible to create the ​second​ layer and print it in the console.

The input consists of a row that gives the dimensions of the area and the next rows give the layout of the first layer.

These are some examples of the first and the expected second layer:

One of the simple examples

[image: One of the simple examples]

An examples consisting of more bricks

[image: An examples consisting of more bricks]

I understand how the bricks on the second layer should be, and as the examples show there is logic and consistency in the numbers of the bricks and how they are put. The next example shatters that logic and consistency that I found with the two examples.

Large area of bricks

[image: Large area of bricks]

My question to you is:
Do you find any sequence in the numbers and do you think they are just some sort of "id"s of the bricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made good a start at breaking the problem space down to the smallest possible domain by focusing on the patterns of the numbers. But, perhaps you've misunderstood the domain. Perhaps the problem should not be broken down based upon how the numbers represent each brick.

The domain is presented in such a way that there is seemingly no way to provide uniform layers of bricks that can be laid in an easy cross hatch pattern. While this appears to be a constraint, it just may be the key requirement. Specifically,

> The second layer ( in an effort to make the brickwork really strong)
> must be created in away that no brick in it lies exactly on a brick
> from the first layer.

That is a very specific *requirement* that might easily be ignored in problem definition because it is disguised as a constraint. If taken as a requirement it becomes quite clear that the is brick is not where to look for a solution. It is the *intersection* of bricks that defines the problem space.

Knowing that, the diagrams very clearly show how the intersections are defined: intersections exist at each 1/2 brick. That is precisely why the creator of this problem had to give you two indices for each brick.

**Given**:

- A layer two brick cannot overlay a brick from the first layer
- Numbered bricks with each half having the same number

**When**:

Laying a brick on the second layer

**Then**:

Any of the following may be true about the overlap of the bricks:

- Matching layer-two numbers don't lay upon matching layer-one numbers
- One and only one layer two number matches one and only one layer one number if they are the same numbers on both layers

The following is not allowed in the overlap:

- Both layer one and layer two numbers are the same
- Matching layer-two numbers are not laid upon matching layer-one numbers

***This all means:***

1. There are two Cartesian planes of dimensions M×N
2. One overlays the other
3. Place the input numbers on a grid of M×N dimensions

***Problem to solve:***

Place the layer two numbers onto the upper grid so that like numbers remain adjacent to each other (1,1; 2,2; etc) in either direction while no two matching numbers from above are in the same grid locations of matching numbers below.

If the algorithm you derive cannot achieve that goal, then it is an impossible grid.

Hope that's helpful.